# How do I fix a bifold closet door that keeps popping open?

Tags: doors, closet

Randomly, my bifold closet door keeps popping open. One side stays shut but the other just bounces back ever so slightly and I can’t get it to stay shut. My cats have caught on to this and have been wreaking havoc in my closet every time I turn my back.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: If sure it is not the cats opening it, then tension/stress.  Something is too tight when the door is closed.  Might just be simple as a bubble of paint.

Comment: Is there some sort of spring mechanism that puts a bit of compression into the door when it's closed? If so, then do you feel a bit of resistance when you close the door, indicating that the spring is in fact supplying that bit of compression?

Comment: @popham Yes, generally there is. Did you note my answer?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the door that's popping open is *slightly* off vertical so that when you close it against the spring in the center, the (very slight) spring pressure is pushing it open.

To check this, close the door (block it closed with a partially full laundry basket if necessary), and look at the gap between the door and frame. If it looks uneven, that's likely the issue.

- Technically, you loosen the screw that holds the top pivot point, move the pivot point bracket in the top track, then tighten the screw back up.
- In practice, open the door all the way so that the two pieces are touching, then give the top corner of the door a whack with the palm of your hand. This should nudge it slightly toward the frame. Close the door and see if it remains shut. Repeat the whacks until it does.
- If, after a couple of whacks, it appears that the gap hasn't changed, you may have to get out the screwdriver, open the door about 1/2 way, push yourself into the closet and loosen the screw a smidge so the pivot point can move.
- After you've got the door adjusted, tighten the screw holding the pivot point in place so it can't move.

Comment: my experience is that bifold closet doors are adjustable, change the bottom support position by lifting it up or change the location of the top hole.

Comment: Very true, @TigerGuy. I just know that when I have issues with mine, I just smack the top back a bit. I should probably get in there with a driver to tighten the top pivot mount, but for the 1-2 times/year I have to think about it, it's not been worth it yet.